# ping a given list of servers

Tags: unix, ping

Given a .csv of websites e.g.

```
1,google.com
2,facebook.com
3,stackoverflow.com
.
.
.
```

and a script which outputs only the website address:

```
awk -F',' '{print $2}'
```

Is it possible to pipe `ping` onto the script in order to ping each website?

Comment: Check out `xargs`, or a shell `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop and the bash's `read` builtin, saying that the file contains comma separated values:

```
while IFS="," read -r id server
do
   ping "$server"
done < your_file
```